# Find $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{7}\ln\left(\frac{1+\sin(x)}{1-\sin(x)}\right)\ln\left(\frac{1+\cos(x)}{1-\cos(x)}\right)\sec(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I just want to know how to find the value of $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{7}\ln\left(\frac{1+\sin(x)}{1-\sin(x)}\right)\ln\left(\frac{1+\cos(x)}{1-\cos(x)}\right)\sec(x)dx$$ Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Me too ! Could you tell what you tried ?

Comment: According to Mathematica this is equal to $\zeta(3)\simeq 1.20206$, so it might help limit down a bit the search.

Comment: @HansOlo. There is an explicit antiderivative.

Comment: The tangent half-angle substitution is over there waiving its arms and screaming “Pick me! Pick me!”

Comment: @DavidH. Nice comment and hint !

Comment: @DavidH I did that, giving $\int_0^1\frac{-8}{7}\ln\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)\frac{ln(t)}{1-t^2}dt$

Comment: @Asv That’s right. Next, what do you know about linear fractional transformations, i.e., $t=\frac{a+bu}{c+du}$?

Comment: @DavidH if you make the transform $t=\frac{u-1}{u+1}$ you get $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{-4}{7}\frac{\ln(u)}{u}\ln\left(\frac{u-1}{u+1}\right)du$ is this what you meant?

Comment: @Asv Indeed, though I would have gone with $t=\frac{1-u}{1+u}$.

Comment: @DavidH I did IBP, then am left with $\frac{4}{7}\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln^2(u)}{u^2-1}du$

Comment: @DavidH Thanks a lot, I solved it